# How to change background color in FAB buton?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried several options but none of them work and all the documentation I find is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Rodriguez Manuel Joaquin, i would suggest you try with the following line:`buttonName.setBackgroundTintList(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.COLOR));`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: buttonName.setBackgroundTintList(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.COLOR));